# Understanding uxth instruction in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

Analyzing a decompiled ARM binary, I came across these instructions

```
...
mov r7, #0
uxth r0, r7
...
add r7, r7, #1
uxth r4, r7
...
```

From ARM docs:

> `UXTH{cond} {Rd}, Rm {,rotation}` extends a 16-bit value to a 32-bit value. It does this by:
>
> 1. Rotating the value from Rm right by 0, 8, 16, or 24 bits.
> 2. Extracting bits[15:0] from the value obtained.
> 3. Zero extending to 32 bits.

This really confused me and raised a lot of questions:

- Doesn't mov already operate on 32-bit registers ?
- What is the purpose of zero extending a zero using `uxth` ?
- Why not just load the value directly into r0 ?

Comment: My first guess would be an unoptimized compilation of `uint16_t a; uint32_t b,c; a=0; b=a; /* ... */ a++; c=a;`.  In other words, a compiler that unthinkingly emits `uxth` for every unsigned conversion of 16-bit to 32-bit integer, without noticing that it could propagate the constant.

Comment: What compiler produced this executable?  Is it possible that `uxth r0, r7` could be reachable with a branch from somewhere else, not just from fall-through from the previous instruction?  Perhaps it's the top of a loop, with the `mov r7, #0` outside the loop, so it's redundant on the first iteration (and probably some future ones).  Use `objdump -drwC --visualize-jumps`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems it's merely doing an `AND` with `0xffff`.

```
uxth r4, r7
```

Let's apply the operations written in the manual in order.

*1. Rotating the value from Rm right by 0, 8, 16, or 24 bits.*

This is not set so no rotation.

*2. Extracting bits[15:0] from the value obtained.*

*3. Zero extending to 32 bits.*

These steps together is the same as `& 0xffff`.

So basically it's `& 0xffff` <s>written in an unnecessarily complicated way</s>. Oops, even the compiler generates this code so this seems to be the quite standard way to zero extend 16 bits in 32-bit ARM. Sorry for the misinformation.

```
mov r7, #0
uxth r0, r7
```

These lines are probably intentionally written in a complicated way, or it is from unoptimized compilation, or the compiler is so bad even with optimization. Just do `mov r0, #0`.

<sub>Somehow uxth reads like ux..</sub>

Comment: Are you sure it means `& 0xffff` ? Let's say I have 0x0000001. Step 2 > 0x0001. Step 3 > 0x00010000

Comment: @AminGuermazi Zero extending `0x0001` which is `1` is `1`. Zero extending `1` to any number of bits is `1`.

Comment: So it's keeping the number the same ? Weird

Comment: @AminGuermazi Yes it is keeping the number the same with `1`, but if the number were `0x10000`, zero extending the lower 16 bits using `uxth` in the same would be `0` because `0x10000 & 0xffff == 0`.

Comment: Wait, it's extracting the lower 2 bytes of the number ? Isn't that the same as movw ?

Comment: @AminGuermazi Yes it is. `GCC` uses it with `-O3` optimization, so it seems to be the fast way to do so. https://godbolt.org/z/YfqqzbMha

Comment: @AminGuermazi BTW `movw` can only load a constant. It cannot copy between registers.

Comment: Oh so thats why the compiled doesn't use it. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

This instruction is intended to help with 16 bit variables.   Your immediate moves do not make sense much but what if I have a 16 bit variable at address 0x1001?   To avoid an unaligned access you want to do a 32 bit load, shift right 8 then and with 0x0000FFFF (which automatically give you your sign extension.  To do this normally you need another register, and a couple-few instructions.  Now its two instructions and not necessarily need another register.  What you would see before this was shift left 16 then shift right to avoid the register giving the mask and zero pad, but that is two instructions.

Comment: I didn't ask the question, but thank you for letting me make sense on why such a weird looking instruction at first glance exist. Yeah I'm too used to x86 with all its unaligned access.

Comment: wasnt sure what the question was.  The exact code you showed, should have optimized out, but you didnt show a complete example that generated that code.  And I didnt find your question obvious...

Comment: Umm.. it's more like *I* didn't ask the question, rather than I *didn't* ask the question. I meant I'm not the OP.. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand your comment.  But your original question can be interpreted different ways and if you are asking why that instruction was used, because it does not change the value in the register, then need to understand how that code was generated, what was compiled, what compile settings generated that code.  Was it not optimized, etc...

Comment: which is what is covered in the other answer.

Comment: I think there still some confusion here.. I didn't ask the question. I answered the question. I'm not the OP (original poster).